For each title, calculate the difference between sources in Looker Studio
I'm new to Looker and don't have a strong grasp of it yet. Running into lots of little roadblocks. Currently, I have the following problem.
I have a dataset that has columns for Title, State, Source, and Count. I want to create a chart that, for each Title, subtracts the count for one state from another and displays that difference. How can I do this?
